# Symfony Pass variable to template on every refresh

Tags: php, variables, layout, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I know there's a few threads on here about passing variables to the template using partials or slots.   My question is, how do you define that variable so that no matter what page you are on, the variable is still accessible.   I know each one of the actions "extend" `sfActions` but is there a way to access that and set an action for the site as a whole?

**Edit:**

Every user has a field in the sfUser table that I would like displayed at the top of every page.  Here is the code I would like to use but I'm not sure where to put or or how to pass it to the partial on the template page.

```
$this->user = $this->getUser()->getGuardUser();
$this->activeitems = $this->user->getActiveItems();
```

Comment: What kind of variable do you need? Where is it comes from and depends on what?

Comment: and tell us what you want to do, in the context of your project.

Comment: I have updated my question with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every template, you can access your user information using `$sf_user`. It returns a `myUser` object.

If you've installed sfGuard, this class should extends `sfGuardSecurityUser`. And inside this class, you can retrieve the sfGuardUser object using `->getGuardUser()` method.

So to retrieve this information inside any templates, you can do:

```
$activeitems = $sf_user->getGuardUser()->getActiveItems();
```

Comment: Can I do that in the template itself by doing `<?php $activeitems = $sf_user->getGuardUser()->getActiveItems(); ?>` ?

Comment: @djcloud23 Yes of course, I told you *inside any templates* :)